# register each phone using OTP in production

Tags: clickatell

Do we need to register each and every phone number using OTP for sending sms in bulk.
for example, if we have 60-70 phones to send the sms, then do we need to register all the 60-70 phones numbers using OTPs for all the 60-70 phone numbers?

thanks to reply.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to "register" phone numbers that you are sending to. See the documentation for more info: https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/rest-api-send-message/